# Germany: Extending residence permit (Aufenthaltstitel) after becoming self-employed

Tags: working-visas, germany, resident-permit, freelance

I have lived in Germany with job specific *Aufenthaltstitel* for more than 3 years. I have worked in two companies in this time, and when I got hired for the second job I went to *Ausländerbehörde* and got a new *Aufenthaltstitel* with the new job specified as my work place.

My *Aufenthaltstitel* also includes the following line:
“**Selbständige Tätigkeit gestattet**”

My *Aufenthaltstitel* expires in half a year.

I am considering joining an American company to work remotely and I'd like to register as a freelancer or self-employed, whatever fits, so I am able to issue invoices and pay tax here in Germany.

I understand that my current status allows me to be self-employed, 
but I don't know **if I can *extend* the residence permit being self-employed**?

Any direction in terms and maybe sites where I could read about this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully extended my residence permit based on self-employment. I had to bring a bunch of papers (some helpful guidance can be found [here](https://medium.com/@imcatnoone/how-to-get-your-german-freelance-visa-without-losing-your-sanity-8fa68b39431a#.e0kym0e16), but be sure to consult local Ausländerbehörde (for me it is [Berlin](https://www.berlin.de/labo/willkommen-in-berlin/aufenthalt/erwerbstaetigkeit/selbststaendige-taetigkeit/)).

They gave me the visa based on business plan, recommendation letters and a sheet of profit and loss and a personal statement, and I needed to register with pension and medical insurances and bring confirmations for these too. I only got the extension for 1 year and will need to provide my tax return papers to Ausländerbehörde for the extension.

One thing to note – the mark regarding “Selbständige Tätigkeit gestattet” in my visa did not allow to become self-employed, but rather to have some self-employment along with my main job at a company. I needed ausländerbehörde to specifically allow "Erwerbstätigkeit" (more about [that](https://www.berlin.de/labo/willkommen-in-berlin/aufenthalt/erwerbstaetigkeit/beschaeftigung/)), which I think means any jobs, employed or self-employed, are allowed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can extend your residence permit. From [German Residence Act (Aufenthaltsgesetz)](http://dejure.org/gesetze/AufenthG/21.html)

> Einem Ausländer kann eine Aufenthaltserlaubnis zur Ausübung einer
>   freiberuflichen Tätigkeit abweichend von Absatz 1 erteilt werden. Eine
>   erforderliche Erlaubnis zur Ausübung des freien Berufes muss erteilt
>   worden oder ihre Erteilung zugesagt sein. Absatz 1 Satz 3 ist
>   entsprechend anzuwenden. Absatz 4 ist nicht anzuwenden.

As I understand it, you can get a resindence permit not only for specified job but also for self employement. As you are already allowed to be self-employed, I see no problem at all to extend your resindce permit.